# Jetpack Compose - Typography customization not affected in my Text()

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to customize the Typography in my project. But it not affected in my widgets.

**My TypoGraphy customization:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
subtitle1 = TextStyle(
        fontFamily = FontFamily.Monospace,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
        fontSize = 30.sp,
    )
```

**In my Text :**

```
Text(text = "Homemade veg pizza", style = MaterialTheme.typography.subtitle1)
```

**My Output :**

[image]

**My problem:**
Fontsize and fontfamily not changed. It looks same like default text. How to set custom TypoGraphy in Jetpack Compose?

Comment: It should work. In the setContent block are you using the theme with the modifier typography?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti yes, I missed to set theme in setContent block. Thanks for your support again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's my mistake. I figure out.

We need to set the MaterialTheme before use custom TypoGraphy.

In my rootView I place my rootView under the MaterialTheme. Issue fixed.

```
 setContent {
        MaterialTheme {  //I missed this line
            ThemesRootView()
        }
    }
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Quick note. My problem was that I was not seeing changes to type or color etc. in Preview. It's because I was not running the Composable I was trying to preview inside AppNameTheme{}.